# Game Center: Leaderboard retrieve scores

Tags: iphone, game-center, leaderboard

I am developing an Game Center application. One of my leaderboards presents the total score earned by the player. I'm doing this by retrieving the current score of the player stored in the leaderboard and adding the last received score.

The problem seems to be that the values one receive are a little bit outdated. If you submit a score it takes up to 1 hour till you receive this number, though the submitted score shows up in the leader board immediately.

Is this kind of delay related to the sandbox environment or is it a general problem one has to deal with?

Thank in advance

Comment: I don't think the Leaderboards at GC are designed to handle such a thing has a "total score". You'd have to store that data yourself somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the Game Center servers' update time varies significantly, although I can't speak to the production servers (only sandbox).

If you are making your own UI for the leaderboard (as opposed to using Game Center's ViewControllers), I would recommend keeping track of the users' Total Score on the device in a variable and simply updating the Game Center leaderboard each time the user gets more points.  Each time the app launches, you initialize the Total Score variable with whatever the user's GKScore is on the leaderboard.